# What is the proper way to convert something generic to more strict?

Tags: typescript

I have an api service which makes calls to various endpoints and so I have type for the responses extremely generically:

```
export interface ApiResponseItem {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | ApiResponseItem | Array<string | number | boolean>
}

export interface ApiResponse {
  [ index: string ]: string | number | boolean | ApiResponseItem | ApiResponseItem[]
}
```

I have a class that wishes to mutate the response object for a specific api call, and rather than the annoyance of having to type check all of the individual properties, I would like to swap out the interface for a known one...

```
export interface MyResponse {
  count: number,
  items: [
    {
      name: string,
      count: number,
    }
  ],
}
```

So, if my api service does:

```
export interface Config {
  endpoint: string,
  onRequest?: (response: ApiResponse) => void,
};

export class ApiService {

  makeCall () {
    const response = this.httpClient.get(this.config.endpoint);
    if (config.onRequest) { config.onRequest(response); }
  }

  ...
```

and that class implements this, I tried to cast to the known type:

```
  config.onRequest = (response: ApiResponse) {
    const res = response as MyResponse;
    res.items.unshift({ name: 'something' });
  };
```

But typescript doesn't like that......  Is the best thing to do make my interface have an `unknown` type?

```
export interface Config {
  endpoint: string,
  onRequest?: (response: unknown) => void,
};
```

So then I can just have my class do:

```
  config.onRequest = (response: MyResponse) {
    response.items.unshift({ name: 'something' });
  };
  ...
```

Or is there a better way to handle this kind of thing?

Comment: What does "typescript doesn't like that" mean? Is there a specific error message somewhere? Please provide a [mre] with no typos (`(response: ApiResponse) {` is what, an arrow function with no arrow?) or missing declarations, or other inconsistencies (you really want `MyResponse`'s `items` property to be a single element tuple? you want to `unshift` something without a `count` property?) .  Ideally I could just drop your code into a standalone IDE like [the TS Playground](//tsplay.dev/wOPJMN) and work on it immediately without dealing with issues unrelated to your question.

Comment: @jcalz yes, that is stripped down example code-- not intended to be real code.  "Typescript doesn't like that" means it gave me an error.  My question is simple:  is there a better way to substitute a loose/generic type with a stricter more known type, or is returning `unknown` the best practice?

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question because I lack the context to understand it. If you present a [mre] which reproduces the error you're alluding to, maybe I'll get it. Generally the goal for example code is to orient people quickly so any time they spend goes toward answering the question. Anything that distracts from this (e.g., syntax errors) runs counter to that goal. It doesn't need to be "real" code, but it does need to actually demonstrate the issue in question.

Comment: I promise I'm engaging in good faith here and I'm hoping you are doing the same. If you want to leave the question as-is, maybe someone else will come along who can give you the help you're asking for. Good luck!